# QR Code Event Extension - Doesn't take us to Checkin page

Tags: civievent, extension, mailing

I have enabled the QR Code Checkin extension.  I have enabled the 3 permissions suggested to allow a user to check attendees in.  The QR Code token is available for event participants in email.  The email goes correctly with a qr code.

I am logged in as administrator but when I use a QR code to access the attendance checkin I'm just sent to the dashboard of civi instead of the person's checkin.

Does anyone have any experience of this that could help me understand where we're going wrong?

We use wordpress and Civi 5.53

Comment: Could you specify which extension your are using - I think there are two or three extensions that do that

Comment: I'm using the QR Code Checkin maintained by Jamie Jamie McClelland.  There was an error with updating to attended but I worked out that was to do with having to have attendees as Attendee rather than delegate.    I have seen that refreshing the browser takes you to the correct screen but this won't look professional on the day if you have to do that each time you register someone.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I do not have experience on the one you are using. Just in case here is a link to a possible alternative: https://docs.civicrm.org/eventcheckin/en/latest/